# What are the differences between these two editions of Munkres?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

My course has the book Munkres Topology (Classic Version) Second Edition (ISBN10 : 0134689518) [i.e. 2018 version] as a required book but I already have the previous 2000 version (ISBN10 : 0131816292).

Can anyone tell me what are the differences between these two editions, and are the differences significant enough for me to buy the new book? Note that I might have to do assignments with problems from the book, so that might be of concern if the problems have been changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually a question best asked of your professor. Not only do they know what they'll be assigning, but if they've taught the course for a long time they might even have problem numbers from the old edition.

Comment: @CadeReinberger Guess I'll do that.

Comment: I make be mistaken, but I believe there is a (at least one) problem that was changed or eliminated between versions.